# How do I fix a 'cannot find symbol' error in Java (Scanner)?

Tags: java

```
public class TemperatureChanger
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int c;
        int f;
        int tempFaren;

        System.out.println("Enter temperature in celcius");
        c = keyboard.nextInt();
        tempFaren = (9 *c)/5 + 32;

        System.out.println( " In Fahrenheit that is " + tempFaren );
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the error `TemperatureChanger.java:7: cannot find symbol Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)` during compilation. What do I need to do to fix this.

Comment: You keep getting it, presumably, because you haven't fixed the mistake that produces it. Looks like you are missing an import for the Scanner class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the Scanner before you use it:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Also I do not know if you forgot to paste it, but you also have to give a name to your class.
For instance:

```
public class Change {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `import java.util.Scanner;` or Java wont find the `Scanner` class. Another possibility is to use the full path to the class but that doesn't seem very practical now does it.